# How to show and hide images in swing using timer?

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, timer, event-dispatch-thread

Is there any way I can just show and hide some images according to the input.

I am using character array of "T" and "F", if it is "T" then it will show image, if not then it will disable.

All I did is used `JLabel` and set `ImageIcon` to it. It shows and hides the image, but using timer, it just refreshes whole thing. Like if there is image for a "T" value, and if next loop of timer has "T" value for arr[2] as previous, then it should just stay there instead of refreshing the whole thing i.e. it blinks.

My code is as follows:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
            call();
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 2000);
}

static void call() {

    String S = "";


    for (int i = 0; i < bool.length; i++) {
        bool[i] = r.nextBoolean();
        if (bool[i]) {
            S = S + "T";
        } else {
            S = S + "F";
        }
    }
    System.out.print(S + "\n");

    char[] chars = S.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if ('T' == chars[i]) {
            label[i] = new JLabel(img);
            frame.getContentPane().add(label[i]);
        } else {
            label[i] = new JLabel(img1);
            frame.getContentPane().add(label[i]);
        }
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

All I want is UI which shows and hides the image in certain time intervals, like in Android, I can use `setVisibility` for `TextView`.

Comment: Let's start with `TimerTask` is in appropriate for this task as it does not respect the single thread rules of Swing, you should be using a `javax.swing.Timer`.  I don't know why you are removing the contents of the frame, simply change the icon as required...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TimerTask` is not appropriate for this task, as it does not respect the single thread rules of Swing (see [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details).

Instead, you should be using a `javax.swing.Timer`, which will ensure that the "tick" event is executed within the Event Dispatching Thread.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Blinky01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Blinky01();
    }

    public Blinky01() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            label = new JLabel("0");
            add(label);
            Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    boolean value = (((int) Math.round(Math.random() * 1))) == 0 ? false : true;
                    System.out.println(value);
                    label.setText(value ? "1" : "0");
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.setInitialDelay(0);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One more question, it must be silly but I am new to this. I just want to add background to the JFrame. I tried to add background on my previous code but it was just showing at first, then after next loop it was just showing images of cars, not the background. Is it possible to show cars on top of background without changing background with timer?

Comment: The short answer is yes.  From you example code, you removed all the components from the frame, so it's not surprising nothing else was showing up.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I add background to JFrame in the code you've provided? And also I tried to change the Layout to new GridLayout(2, 6, 10, 10) it is not showing 2 rows and 6 columns. Is there anything else I'd have to do for that?

Comment: Okay. GridLayout worked. I hadn't changed in TestPane() constructor. Thanks. Still curious about the background though.

Comment: There are any number of ways you can get a background image to work, the simplest would be to load your background image and apply it to a `JLabel` and set the frames content pane to be the label.

Comment: I have added an image using 
JPanel() { paintComponent(Graphics g) { Image bg = new ImageIcon(); }
It is just showing this image below all the images. I was looking for some small images on top of background image.

Comment: If I use BufferedImage, how to make it as a background and put other small JLabels on top of that?